# django-ckeditor ignores static storage settings

Tags: django, azure, ckeditor, django-storage, django-ckeditor

I'm using django-ckeditor in admin and django-storages with Azure Storage for static & media files.

All static files in admin are loaded from Azure Storage, but CKEditor's files are not:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://somehost.blob.core.windows.net/blob/admin/js/core.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js"></script>
```

Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, according to [this link](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/issues/294), I need to set MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL to my Azure Storage host.